# NameError: name 'first' is not defined What Can I Do?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")
root.title("Bubble Sort")

def printfirst():
    get1 = w.get()
    get2 = e.get()
    get3 = r.get()
    get4 = t.get()
    get5 = y.get()
    first = Label(root, text= get1 + get2 + get3 + get4 + get5)
    first.pack()

def test():
    get1 = w.get()
    get2 = e.get()
    get3 = r.get()
    get4 = t.get()
    get5 = y.get()
    if get1 > get2:
        first.configure(text= get2 + get1 + get3 + get4 + get5)

te = Label(root, text="Enter 5 Diffrent Numbers")
te.pack()
w = Entry(root)
get1 = w.get()
w.pack()
e = Entry(root)
get2 = e.get()
e.pack()
r = Entry(root)
get3 = r.get()
r.pack()
t = Entry(root)
get4 = t.get()
t.pack()
y = Entry(root)
get5 = y.get()
y.pack()
p = Button(root, text="Print Out", command=printfirst)
p.pack()

gg = Button(root, text="Sort It!", command=test)
gg.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

The error log:

> "Exception in Tkinter callback
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1533, in **call**
>           return self.func(*args)
>         File "C:/Users/lycelab18/Desktop/testt.py", line 29, in test
>           first.configure(text= get2 + get1 + get3 + get4 + get5)
>       NameError: name 'first' is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

In your `test()` function you use `first.configure(...)` before you define `first` var.

You `first` value defined in `printfirst()` doen't exist in `test()` function.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `first` only exists within the scope of the function `printfirst()`, this means you can't access it from within the scope of `test()`.

One way to solve this is to `return first` from the `printfirst()` function, save this variable and then pass it as an argument in the second method; `test(first)`

This will look like this:

```
def printfirst():
    get1 = w.get()
    get2 = e.get()
    get3 = r.get()
    get4 = t.get()
    get5 = y.get()
    first = Label(root, text= get1 + get2 + get3 + get4 + get5)
    first.pack()
    return first

def test(first):
    get1 = w.get()
    get2 = e.get()
    get3 = r.get()
    get4 = t.get()
    get5 = y.get()
    if get1 > get2:
        first.configure(text= get2 + get1 + get3 + get4 + get5)

first = printfirst()
test(first)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, first is not defined in `def test():`
You could define and initialise it as you have done in `def printfirst`

```
def test():
    get1 = w.get()
    get2 = e.get()
    get3 = r.get()
    get4 = t.get()
    get5 = y.get()
    # If this is how you want to initialise it
    first = Label(root, text= get1 + get2 + get3 + get4 + get5)
    first.pack()
    if get1 > get2:
         first.configure(text= get2 + get1 + get3 + get4 + get5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no variable/object called `first` in the function `test()`. You need to assign it before using it. The way you do in `printfirst()`.